# How to make these two sitting side by side?

Tags: css

Sorry for the duplicated question, I've searched for related previous posts, all said adding "float:left" to both DIVs and/or add "display: inline-block", but no joy.

What I want to achieve is something like this: [View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/FI0WK40)

Although I can add some margin/padding to achieve the same result as the image above, but when I resize the browser it's doesn't work as this has to be responsive. Would you please help?

```
<style>
body {
width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
width: 80%;
display: inline-block;
}

.order  {
float: left;
}

.content {
width: 80%;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="order">01/</div>
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class='subject'>HERE IS THE SUBJECT</h2>
        <p>oiwjefoj wefojiwe fjoiwefj woj wefojiwef wefjoiwef wjoeifjow ejowefjoi wfjowefjio wefnoiwjefohwf</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: your wrapper should have the width of 100%. then set the width for order 20% and 80 % for the content and add inline block for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.order {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and change your text size and give margin-top to text to format text.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, I just tried what you suggested, one div for 20% and another one for 80%, I even applied the box-sizing thing on it, but now the "01/" is located at the top left hand corner, I've put a photo on Imgur, do you mind to take a look? http://imgur.com/a/oBXgT

Answer (score 0):

Have the wrapper have `width:100%` then set the for order width for 20% and 80 % for the content and add inline block for each of them.
see this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/cs4tspc0/

Comment: Thanks Nelson, I've just checked the codes that you put on JS Fiddle, but now the "01/" is located at the top left hand corner, which isn't what I want, I've put a photo on Imgur, http://imgur.com/a/oBXgT, do you mind to take a look?

Comment: Its really located at top left corner since it has no margin or padding at all.  I already adjust some padding and widths of the div. Also one more thing. Always remove the margins on h1-h6 tag. Sometimes it ruins your design.
See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/cs4tspc0/2/